# Where can i find google app id, api key, project id and gcm sender id in cloud firestore

Tags: flutter

I had this sample code, but I am not sure where can I find all the fields in my Firebase console.

```
final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
  name: 'test',
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
    googleAppID: '1:1234567:ios:987654',
    gcmSenderID: '987654321',
    apiKey: 'ABC123456789DEF',
    projectID: 'projectId',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in `GoogleServicesInfo.plist` file.

You should be able to see like:

```
<key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
<string>1:111111:ios:222222</string>

<key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
<string>1234567890</string>

<key>API_KEY</key>
<string>ThisIsMyApiKey111</string>

<key>PROJECT_ID</key>
<string>yourId</string>
```